# Why is there is a Compile error: Variable not defined?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Problem1()

Dim nQuarters As Integer    ' number of quarters
Dim nProducts As Integer    ' number of products
Dim wsData As Worksheet     ' worksheet that contains the data
Dim initialRowAddress As String     ' initial row address for sums
Dim initialColumnAddress As String  ' initial column address for sums
Dim salesHigh As Single ' product with the highest annual sales
Dim salesLow As Integer ' product with the lowest annual sales
Dim productSales() As Single    ' array of sales for each product
Dim productCodes() As String    ' array of codes for each product
Dim i As Integer      ' used as an iterator
Dim salesHighProduct As String     ' product with the highest annual sales
Dim salesLowProduct As Integer     ' product with the lowest annual sales

Set wsDatasheet = Worksheets("Problem 1") 'the name of the sheet shoulbe "Problem 1"

' Count the number of quarters and products
With wsData.Range("A1") 'should be "A1"
    nProducts = Range(.Offset(1, 0), _
        .Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
    nQuarters = Range(.Offset(0, 1), _
        .Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count 1
```

The code cannot run because there is error in the offset code.

On wsDatasheet

> Compile error:
>   Variable not defined

Comment: VBA will tell you the error. What does it say when it stops?

Comment: on the code wsDatasheet, compile error: Variable no defined

Answer (score 0):

You want to set object value:

```
Set wsDatasheet = (...)
```

But you don't have wsDatasheet declared. You need to:

Dim wsDatasheet as worksheet

Before you can set its value.